# Why does Word suddenly asks for a file format whenever I open a RTF file?

Tags: microsoft-word

Since a few days my (outdated) Word 2000 shows up a dialog and asks which file converter to use whenever I open a RTF file. (The RTF format is preselected)

Can this be deactivated? I've searched the options but I could not find anything. And I can't remember what started this.

PS: The RTF files are not corrupted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found it out myself:

Certain VBA functions accept a `ConfirmConversion` parameter. If this is used, Word permanently changes the default setting for this parameter in the registry.

This is a [known problem](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B275985&x=11&y=15) with Word.